# Does summing two audio samples affect sampling rate?

Tags: sampling

Original Post: [Electronics Stack Exchange ("Why is my frequency being effectively doubled?")](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/570751/why-is-my-frequency-being-effectively-doubled?noredirect=1#comment1493389_570751)

I'll try to explain everything with detail as this is one will be a hard one to explain.

Essentially what I am trying to achieve is **sum both the left & right channel** to produce a mono signal to be outputted via I2S as the subwoofer line.

The problem I am having right now is that after summing the samples and sending it back to the peripheral I am observing at least double the frequency compare to the input and I have no idea why. Also at lower frequencies the signal looks chopped (see pictures)

What I have done for you is:

- Ensured the I2S Clock is running correctly
- Without summing just sending 1:1 samples and it's a mirror image of the input

The I2S3 DMA is setup as follow:

- Length = 2048 (Tx_BUFF)

The I2S1 DMA is setup as follow:

- Length = 4096 (Rx_BUFF)
- Length - 4096 (Tx_BUFF)

**Code: I2S_HALFCOMPLETE_CALLBACK()**

```
void I2S_HALFCOMPLETE_CALLBACK() {

    int * I2S3_TxBUFF = getI2S3_TxBUFF();
    int INSAMPLE_I2S_MONO[1024];
  
  for (int i = 0; i < 2048; i++) {

    if ((i % 2) == 0){ // L Samples

        INSAMPLE_I2S_MONO[i >> 1] = I2S1_RxBUFF[i];

    } else if ((i % 2) == 1){ // R Samples

      if (inputSourceMode == INPUT_INLINE) {

          INSAMPLE_I2S_MONO[(i - 1) >> 1] += I2S1_RxBUFF[i];
          INSAMPLE_I2S_MONO[(i - 1) >> 1]  =  INSAMPLE_I2S_MONO[(i - 1) >> 1] >> 1;
      }
    }
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < 2048; i++) {

    if ((i % 2) == 0) { // L Samples

    

    }   else if ((i % 2) == 1) { // R Samples

    

    }
      
     if (i < 1024) {
         I2S3_TxBUFF[i] =  INSAMPLE_I2S_MONO[i];
      }

  }


}
```

**CODE: I2S_TRANSFERCOMPLETE_CALLBACK()**

```
void I2S_TRANSFERCOMPLETE_CALLBACK() {

    int * I2S3_TxBUFF = getI2S3_TxBUFF();
    int INSAMPLE_I2S_MONO[1024];

  int * I2S3_TxBUFF = getI2S3_TxBUFF();

  int INSAMPLE_I2S_MONO[1024];
  
  for (int i = 2048; i < 4096; i++) {

    if ((i % 2) == 0) { // L Samples

        INSAMPLE_I2S_MONO[(i >> 1)-1024] = I2S1_RxBUFF[i];
        
    } else if ((i % 2) == 1){ // R Samples

             INSAMPLE_I2S_MONO[((i - 1) >> 1) - 1024] += I2S1_RxBUFF[i];
             INSAMPLE_I2S_MONO[((i - 1) >> 1) - 1024]  =  INSAMPLE_I2S_MONO[((i - 1) >> 1) - 1024] >> 1;

    }

  }

  for (int i = 2048; i < 4096; i++) {

    if ((i % 2) == 0) { // L Samples


    } else if ((i % 2) == 1){ // R Samples


    }


    if (i < 3072) {

        I2S3_TxBUFF[i - 1024] =  INSAMPLE_I2S_MONO[i-2048];

    }
  }
```

Results:
@ 6Hz
[image]

@ 56Hz
[image]

@ 1kHz
[image]

@ 4khz
[image]

**UPDATE 1:**

I still dont have a clue, but since the frequencies are being doubled, does it have to do with feeding the audio samples at half? For example I am receiving a total of 4096 samples but when summing I am only sending back out 2048. Is that why? Its trying to send 2048 within the 4096 sample period?

**UPDATE 2:**

Another gut feeling is coming from adding the two samples together. I feel like it has something to do with the sampling rate. Tried output L + R samples and it works fine, but when I combine them the sample rate is doubled.

Comment: welcome here, might be nice if you linked to your question on electronics.stackexchange.com, where we already multiple weaknesses of your code. Also, no, adding samples doesn't change the rate. How should it? Your frequency isn't doubled, you just have an instable system, probably because your callback takes longer than half a sample period.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Oh perfect I shall. It doesnt I see. Oh amigo, day three on this I gotta start assuming everything. Reasoning being I removed the "summing" operation and just outputting L and R channels and its working so the only difference is the summing operation.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Ill test the callback theory for you, give me a second, but I doubt it.

Comment: that's a typical debugging deadend, you start assuming the impossible instead of the likely but hard to debug. Again, your code probably simply takes too long occasionally – that's hard to see

Comment: @MarcusMüller I see where you're coming from and Ill do it for you so we can cross it out on the white board

Comment: no, you don't, because more likely than that a simple addition is a resampler is that your oscilloscope has a malicious gnome in it ;) You need to start with more likely things!

Comment: @MarcusMüller Alright I got your measurement here. To complete one CB function it takes 1.45mS. And a CB function triggers every 21mS. I am starting to believe into the malicious gnome theory though

Comment: excellent! So we've got headroom. In that case in addition to writing the samples to the TX buffer, also write them into a loooong buffer in RAM, your STM32H753ZI (you **really** should add information like the IC you're using to the question) has plenty RAM, so you should be able to log quite a bit. Then analyze that buffer; is it correct?

Comment: Yes, much headroom we have!  I am not sure if I am following along. So in addition to writing into Tx you want me to write into a dummy array? And you are right, ill mention the MCU in question.

Comment: Looks like the output chip might be thinking that the output sample rate is 2x what you want it to be.  Why don't you try just creating a synthetic output (ignore the input).  And then measure the frequency and see if it is what you expect.

Comment: But the weirdest thing is, when I take the the Rx samples and just shove them into the Tx buffer block it works? Its just whenever I sum them

Comment: When you sum the two input channels together to get a mono signal, do you send the mono signal into both two output channels? Or to one output channel but zero the other channel?

Comment: What I do is when sum it together and add it to both channels

Comment: i ain't suggesting to close, but you might wanna ask this at the [Electrical Engineering stackexchange](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does summing two audio samples affect sampling rate?

No.

Sorry this is one tortured piece of code and it's difficult to read.

A few things to check

1. Are you using "ping pong" buffers for your DMA? You should have two set of buffers that alternate on each frame: one for receiving/sending data and one for working on it.
2. Make sure you I2S configuration is correct in terms of number of channels, frame size, etc. Ideally input and output DMA use the same config.
3. Make sure you don't clip. I'd recommend prescaling the data by -6dB before summing it.
4. Consider simplifying your code.

It should look something like this:

```
int *rxBuf, *txBuf;
int i, tmp;

// get pointers to the current set of "work" buffers
rxBuf = getCurrentDMAReceiveBuffer();
txBuf = getCurrentDMATransmitBuffer();
for(i = 0; i < FRAME_LENGTH; i += 2)
{
  // get both channel samples divide by two and sum
  tmp = rxBuf[i]>>1 + rxBuf[i+1]>>1;
  // write to both channels of the the transmit buffer
  txBuf[i] = tmp;
  txBuf[i+1] = tmp;
}
```

Comment: I do apologize for the messy code. I mean I am doing the fundamentals that youre doing. But ill check it with youre code. I haev also made sure from 2-3 is good.

Comment: well,  you've apologized for your code to both me and Hilmar now. So, clean it up, finally! Remove all the code that doesn't do anything (for example, your empty `if`s), remove the whitespace with no purpose, and then indent/reformat properly. I know this sounds like nitpicking, but clean and mostly, as lean as possible code is really the first step to understanding a problem. It takes away both distractions, and reduces the number of bugs you might accidentally miss.

Comment: @MarcusMüller, boys or girls. It worked. It finally works.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the summing.

Using Hilmar algorithm above got it working.

The difference between Hilmar's algorithm and mine is that his fills up the buffer with both (L+R), so for example if the array is something like this
int * dummyArray[8] all 8 elements are occupied with L+R samples.

The difference with my algorithm is that if we have the same int * dummyArray[8] it would populate L+R samples up to half of the array, so all elements within 0...3 would only have L+R.

Reasoning being an array with [1024] samples plus another array with [1024] samples should still have [1024] elements. This could be the double frequency?

Comment: Then depends on how you configure you I2S output stream. If you configure this as two channels as well and only fill the first half of the buffer, you will indeed see frequency doubling. The stereo channels are interleaved so if you write is a linear area, you are throwing away half of the samples, your output will appear to be up-sampled by two. Your method would work only if you can configure the output I2S as a mono stream.

Comment: @Hilmar The I2S Peripheral is stereo by default and cant be changed to mono. SAI you can.  I see, thats where I went wrong. I was throwing away half the samples but only because if you add to things together it doesnt increase the elements but cuts it in half. Like explained above